# Collate three or more consecutive terms in a column with bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I ask help to solve a problem I tried to figure out myself with no success. Shortly, I need to process very large tabular data files with structure:

```
14       R
16       I
21       B
22       C
23       Q
24       E
33       R
34       L
41       K
62       F
63       F
64       M
88       B
```

and so on... What I trying to do on these sorted ascending data is to collate items in the second column corresponding to chunks of three or more consecutive terms in the first column. So, the expected output from the above data should be:

```
21-24    BCQE
82-64    FFM
```

The piece of code I ended up so far is:

```
prev=0
val=$(prev + 1)
while read -r n a ; do
    if [[ ${n} == ${val} ]] 
        t="$( "$a" + ( "$(a - 1)" ) )"  ; then
        echo "$t"
    fi
    prev=$n
done < table
```

But does not work.

Comment: I think you mean `62-64    FFM` as result, not `82-64    FFM`, right?

Comment: Does this _need_ to be done in bash? It's a horrible tool for text parsing. It will make everything much slower than it needs to be (as in several times slower), the syntax is obscure and it is very easy to get it wrong. Would you be open to non-bash solutions?

Comment: Also, do you really want to remove all lines that are not consecutively numbered?

Comment: Yes, It should be 62-64. Sorry for the typo. Bash (or awk) is mandatory because this code is part of a large bash script. Yes, lines not belonging to a chunk of at least 3 consecutive numbers should not selected/printed in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted elsewhere, bash is probably not the best tool for the job, it's probably easier to do this in Perl or awk. Even so:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

print() {
# "${array[*]}" joins the elements with the first characters of IFS as separator
# so we set IFS to the empty string so that the elements are simply concatenated 
    local IFS=
    if (( end - start > 1 ))    # more than two consecutive numbers, concatenate
    then
        printf "%s-%s\t%s\n" "$start" "$end" "${chars[*]}"
    elif (( start == end ))                     # single number, nothing special
    then
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$start" "${chars[0]}"
    elif (( end - start == 1 ))      # two consecutive numbers, print separately
    then
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$start" "${chars[0]}" "$end" "${chars[1]}"
    fi
}

# An initial read
read -r n a
chars=( "$a" )
start=$n
end=$n

while read -r n a
do 
    if (( n - end == 1 ))  # consecutive numbers, store for printing
    then
        chars+=( "$a" )
        end=$n
        continue           # move to next line
    fi
    print                  # Break in numbers, print stored set
    chars=( "$a" )         # reset variables
    start=$n
    end=$n
done

print                      # print last set
```

If you don't want the other rows, you can remove the `elif` blocks in the `print` function.

Example output:

```
14  R
16  I
21-24   BCQE
33  R
34  L
41  K
62-64   FFM
88  B
```

Comment: This work perfect and it is just bash. Thank so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'function out() { if (start != "") { if (start == prev) printf("%s\t%s\n", prev, string); else printf("%s-%s\t%s\n", start, prev, string) } } $1 != prev + 1 { out(); start = $1; string = "" } { prev = $1; string = string $2 } END { out() }' file
14      R
16      I
21-24   BCQE
33-34   RL
41      K
62-64   FFM
88      B
```

The `awk` program:

```awk
function out() {
    if (start != "") {
        if (start == prev)
            printf("%s\t%s\n", prev, string)
        else
            printf("%s-%s\t%s\n", start, prev, string)
    }
}

$1 != prev + 1 { out(); start = $1; string = "" }

{ prev = $1; string = string $2 }

END { out() }
```

This program keeps track of the previous number from the 1st column in `prev`, and the concatenation of the 2nd column in `string`.  When the previous 1st column is one less than the current 1st column, all that happens is that `prev` and `string` are updated.

When there's a "gap" in the numbering, `out()` is called to output the collected data together with the interval recorded.  The function is also called at the end of the input.

A word-for-word equivalent thing for an `sh` shell:

```sh
out () {
    if [ -n "$start" ]; then
        if [ "$start" = "$prev" ]; then
            printf '%s\t%s\n' "$prev" "$string"
        else
            printf '%s-%s\t%s\n' "$start" "$prev" "$string"
        fi
    fi
}

while read -r num str; do
    if [ "$num" -ne "$(( prev + 1 ))" ]; then
        out
        start=$num
        string=""
    fi

    prev=$num
    string=$string$str
done <file

out
```

I just noticed this would combine even when there's only two lines following each other numerically.  I might correct this later, but I'll leave it here for now.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply. Your code works well but the output needs to be edited to get rid of single and double occurrences (i,e. under the threshold. Useful reply anyway.

Comment: @MaurizioCirilli Yeah, sorry for not correcting it, I've been busy. I might still come back to it at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '{if(p+1==$1){c+=1}else{ if(c>1){printf "%s-%s %s\n", b, p, s;} c=0;s=""}} c==1{b=p} {p=$1;s=s$2}' file
```

This time a bit more readable with explanations:

```
awk '{ 
  if(p+1==$1){
    c+=1 # increment the counter if the value is consecutive
  } else {
    if(c>1){
      # print the begin and end values with the concatenated string
      printf "%s-%s %s\n", b, p, s;
    }
    c=0 # reset the counter
    s="" # reset the string to print
  }
}
c==1{b=p} # set the begin value
{p=$1;s=s$2} # set the previous variable and the string for the next loop
' file
```

Tested with GNU `awk` and `mawk`

Comment: I checked out this code and it works perfectly. Thank so much for your help. As a note: hat is the parameter to change in order to move the threshold from 3 to a different higher number?